# Evaluating a nasty integral that Mathematica can't deal with

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The nasty integral is 
$\displaystyle \frac{\lambda}{4\pi \varepsilon }\left [ z\mathbf{\hat{z}}\int_{-L}^{L}\frac{1}{\left ( x^{2}+z^{2} \right )^{3/2}}dx \right ]$

What Mathematica returned was

> {0,0,ConditionalExpression[([Lambda] L)/(2 [Pi] z [Epsilon] Sqrt[L^2+z^2]),Im(z)^2<=Re(z)^2[And](Im(z/L)>1[Or]Im(z/L)<-1[Or]Re(z/L)!=0)[And](Sqrt[-((Im(z) Re(z))/(Im(L) Re(L)))][NotElement][DoubleStruckCapitalR][Or]Im(z) ((Re(L) Re(z))/Im(L)+Im(z))<=Re(z) ((Im(L) Im(z))/Re(L)+Re(z))[Or]Re(Sqrt[-((Im(z) Re(z))/(Im(L) Re(L)))])>=1)]}

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The cube is making integrals otherwise it was just standard results

Comment: WAT? ... As to the original post, your integral depends on how $z$ is related to $L$ (is $z>L$? $z<L$? $z=L$?), so Mathematica is doing the best it can.

Comment: Try to add `Assumptions->L>0&&Element[z,Reals]&&z!=0` as an option to `Integrate` (in case those assumptions are true, of course).

Comment: This integral is not difficult. Try the substitution $x = z \tan \theta$.

Comment: @okrzysik Good start. Been ages since i did these manually but I can remember this trig identity you posted. Will get my hands dirty.

Comment: Another successful substitution is $x=z\sinh(\theta)$.

Comment: The antiderivative does not mak any problem. The conditions are introduced when using the bounds since, beside you, nobody knows if $L$ and $z$ are real or complex.

Comment: I'm not sure what you typed in but, for what it's worth, I found the result quite easily with Mathematica using: `Integrate[1/(x^2 + z^2)^(3/2), {x, 0, L}, Assumptions -> {L > 0, z > 0}]`.

Comment: It was the "Assumption" function that I left out.

Comment: One notable fact about the $x=z \tan \theta$ is that, in the context of the electric field of a finite wire, it has a geometric interpretation: $\theta$ is the angle between the $z$-axis and $\mathbb{r}$, so one essentially is choosing to integrate w/r/t this angle rather than the position along the wire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to find the electric field due to finite wire, right?

\begin{align*}
  \mathbf{E}_{z} &= \frac{\lambda}{4\pi \varepsilon} \mathbf{z} \times
           2\int_{0}^{L} \frac{dx}{(x^{2}+z^{2})^{3/2}} \\
        &= \frac{\lambda}{4\pi \varepsilon} \mathbf{z} \times
           2\left[ \frac{x}{z^{2} \sqrt{x^{2}+z^{2}}} \right]_{x=0}^{L} \\
        &= \frac{\lambda}{2\pi \varepsilon} \mathbf{z} \times
           \frac{L}{z^{2} \sqrt{z^{2}+L^{2}}}
\end{align*}

Comment: You know your stuff.